# Overriding NSLog for project and third parties

Tags: ios, objective-c, console, nslog

I'm trying to override the NSLog method for the entire project and third parties to add some logic to it, for example - if the logged message has the string "dog" in it, replace it with a dog emoji and then continue.

Is there a way to override the method such that third parties I use will also be affected by that?

Is there a different way to catch console output, modify it and only then print it?

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible. Better use frameworks that allow you to inject your own logger.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it.

```
#define NSLog(...) CustomLogger(__VA_ARGS__);

void CustomLogger(NSString *format, ...) {
    va_list argumentList;
    va_start(argumentList, format);
    NSMutableString *message = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:argumentList];
    
    NSRange dogRange = [message rangeOfString:@"dog"];
    if (dogRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        [message replaceCharactersInRange:dogRange withString:@""];
    }
    
    NSLogv(message, argumentList);

    va_end(argumentList);
}
```

Comment: where should this code go in the program to affect all frameworks?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you import file that contains this code in the places where you import frameworks